# How to read value from HTML text input?

Tags: php, html, input, textinput

I have a very simple contact us form having name email, phone number and submit button. On submit button click I want to send email to some specific mailID. However after so many attempts of $GET, $_POST I am not able to read values from text boxes.

Here is my html code in view -

```
    <table>
<tr>
<td style="width:10%"></td>
<td>
<div class="section1 jumbotron appointment-form text-center">
    <div class="container">
    <form action="thankyou" method="post"  class="form-group text-left">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12">First Name</div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12">Last Name</div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12">Your Email</div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="col-sm-12">Phone</div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="phone" name="phone"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-12">Your Message</div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <textarea class="form-control message" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">

            <div class="col-sm-9"><a class="btn-link"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="sub-btn"/></a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**And my PHP function goes like **

```
    <?php
function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
         }
$fname = $lname = $email = $phone = $comment = "";
      $fname = $_POST["firstname"];
            $lname = $_POST["lastname"];
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
            $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
            $message= test_input($_POST["message"]);




$to = "****@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject from button";
$txt = "My Message" ;
$headers = "From: info@***.org";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

 ?>
```

---

I have tried

and in thankyou page tried to read the data as $var = $_POST['firstname']
but with no luck.

Can someone please help me in here

Comment: You haven't used any of the tools that a framework like cakephp gives you, and judging from this question seems that you have not any idea about what a framework could do for you. I suggest you to start reading the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/) and go through all the tutorials

Comment: @arilia :  Yes thats true, I am a asp.net developer. And this is a NGO project, helping them as a volunteer. Since this is an existing project made in PHP couldnt develop this in ASP.Net.  though I have tried to read many sites for quick help but coudn't made it.

Comment: There is *zero* CakePHP code in this question. I've updated the tags to reflect the actual question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code and tested it on my local server. It seems that your **name attribute** in your **input tag** has a capital letter N (firstName). $_POST & $_GET are case sensitive.

and also, try to use this function on every php you are coding so that you can monitor what you are receiving.

```
function pr($var) {
      echo '<pre>';
  print_r($var);
      echo '</pre>';
}
```

For example:

```
pr($_POST);
pr($_GET);
pr($_REQUEST);
```

Good Luck!